# Blank page when i make a pushasync to another page (only in ios(ipad)

Tags: c#, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

My MAC (mojave) was updated in the last days, xcode was upgraded from 10 to 11 and visual studio for mac in the last version (i dont know the numbers sorry).

I am working on a project in xamarin forms that until before the update worked well for both android and ios (the mac is only to generate the buils and deploy for my ipad), after the update my application has not worked correctly, since that after loading the login page, I do a pushasync to my contentpage home (which is the masterdetailpage), at this moment in ipad and in the xcode simulator the app is totally blank, does not crash, debugging the software It does its normal route, but does not launch the page indicated in the home as the navigation page (which is another content page with a listview).

please tell me options to keep trying to launch this application correctly

Comment: I would suggest performing a little experiment. Create a new solution and choose an empty masterdetaipage project template. Check if you are able to navigate to all pages as you would expect.

Comment: if you are pushing a MasterDetailPage you are doing something wrong.  A MasterDetail should be the root, not contained in a NavigationPage.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page#creating-a-masterdetailpage

Comment: im using the project with this way because i have a login page first, when the app is launched,the code chooses if it keeps me at startup or does a pushasync at startup

Comment: i updated all the references of packages inside my solution (nuget) and the code is working :S